# how to understand below vim script entries?

Tags: vim

Question 1:
I only know the bash script like this `let var = value`, but how to understand the mean of the below grammar under vim?

```
let g:counter += 1 
return g:counter . '. '
```

Question 2:
What’s the means by `'<C-\>^>'`, what is the key sequence in vim?

```
map '<C-\>^>'
```

I want to append my question, please forgive me,

the vim key map is like this

```
map <C-\>^] :GtagsCursor<CR>
```

I press key like 
`Ctrl-\` `Shift-.` and press `]`
 this doesn't work, what's the matter?

Comment: Q1: Syntax error in expression (error token is ":counter")

Comment: Q2: probably `C->` and then `^`.

Comment: The question is using vim syntax, not bash; I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: `<C-\>^]` - First `<C-\>` is ``Ctrl-\`` then you have `^` which is `Shift-6` then `]`. You should never be pressing `Shift-.` in this sequence.

Comment: hi, I am wrong typing, I did like what you said, but it didn't work, and now I changed the map <C-]> :GtagsCursor<CR>, it seems that works nice. how's that?

Comment: Also it might be the case where `^]` is a special character in vim. Its equivalent to `esc`. You might want to check that.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:

the two lines should be in a  `function`. otherwise the `return` doesn't make any sense.

also the global variable `g:counter` should be already defined.

then the first line, just does as same as:

```
let g:counter = g:counter+1
```

so increment the variable `g:counter` by `1`.

The 2nd line:

```
return g:counter . '. '
```

for example, after increment, the variable value is 10, then the line returns a string `10. (space)`

the first dot concatenates two strings. first string is the variable value, which is converted into string type automatically. and the second string is `'. '`

Question 2:

```
map <C-\>^>
```

Note that I took the single quote from your map command away.

The key sequence is:

<kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd><kbd>Shift-6</kbd><kbd>Shift-.</kbd>

<kbd>shift-6</kbd> is <kbd>^</kbd>

<kbd>Shift-.</kbd> is <kbd>></kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question, you should probably type `:help eval.txt` or `:help usr_41.txt` inside Vim and read a good chunk of it.